# What is an appropriate expression/idiom for "adding argument/point to a discussion"

Tags: expressions, idiom-requests

I am searching for an expression/idiom describing a situation of adding an argument or a valid point to a heated discussion.

For example: I have read an article about something that relates to a bigger subject being disputed nowadays and I want to share it on twitter, facebook, etc. saying

> ... this article _____  to a debate/discussion about ...

Comment: This article *encapsulates* the issues under debate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the verb **contributes** or the phrase **makes a valuable contribution to**.

We say things like "Name-calling does not contribute anything intelligent to the debate" and "He made a valuable contribution to the debate by pointing out ...."

Comment: Yes, "makes a valuable contribution to" fits my needs, thank you.